# Mozilla Push Server is returning a 405

Tags: firefox, web-push

**To put it plainly**: a user has a (Firefox) endpoint and receives web push. But sometimes Mozilla Push Server returns a `405` and the push is never sent/received.

**What I know :**

- the event is sporadic, therefore cannot be reproduced
- it can happen to a well opt-in user to push notification
- it is not restricted to a specific Firefox version
- I only send notification without encrypted payload data (the aim is just to "wake up" the *ServiceWorker*)
- the returned status code `405` from Mozilla Push Server is not listed in their [documentation](http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#errors)
- nor does it contain an `errno` label

Have you ever experienced this ?

Comment: The best thing to do would be opening an issue in https://github.com/mozilla-services/autopush.

Comment: Will do ! I'll update this post accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in this [issue](https://github.com/mozilla-services/autopush/issues/575), our requests used an unallowed method (`PUT`). As we actually have two types of endpoint in our database:

```
https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/*
https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/*
```

the allowed methods are respectively:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
```

So a `POST` method request is a safe one.